# Xpath keeps selecting all objects of the given class instead of the first

Tags: xpath

This one has me stumped., I'm trying to select the first `class = csb-quantity-listbox` object of the below using the XPATH `//select[@class='csb-quantity-listbox'][1]`, but instead of selecting the first quantity listbox it's selecting ALL the listboxes on the page with that class (see image below).

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<div class="gwt-product-detail-products-container">
   <div class="gwt-product-detail-products-header-column">
   </div>
   <div id="gwt-product-detail-widget-id-12766" class="gwt-product-detail-widget">
    <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-image-column ui-draggable" title="12766">
        <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-options-column">
        </div>
        <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-price-column">
        </div>
        <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-quantity-panel">
                <select class="csb-quantity-listbox" name="quantity_12766"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="gwt-bundle-add-to-cart-btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gwt-product-detail-widget-id-10617" class="gwt-product-detail-widget">
        <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-image-column ui-draggable" title="10617">
            <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-options-column">
            </div>
            <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-price-column">
            </div>
            <div class="gwt-product-detail-widget-quantity-panel">
                <select class="csb-quantity-listbox" name="quantity_10617"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="gwt-bundle-add-to-cart-btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: you open much more divs than close

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put brackets around the statement before the `[1]`

Like so:

```
(//select[@class='csb-quantity-listbox'])[1]
```